# Storage is undefined in Providers of Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, undefined, provider

I'm trying to access my Storage at providers, but it's undefined inside providers. In others classes Storage works properly.

Curious: I create a new Ionic2 project, insert Storage into the project and Storage works properly at providers.

In my old and new project the Storage was configurated the same way:

In **app.module.ts** I added this:

> import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
>
> @NgModule({
> ...
> providers: [Storage]
> })

In **providers/service.ts** I added this:

> import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
>
> constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) { }

When I do this: `console.log(this.storage)` is undefined in one project but works in other project.

What can I do to fix it or what can be wrong?

Comment: Compare the package.json file for both project and check the versions.

Comment: Is the same Amin. **"@ionic/storage": "1.1.7"**

Comment: Update: I create another provider inside this project and in this new provider Storage works! Really stranger!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
in  **app.module.ts**

> import { **IonicStorageModule** } from '@ionic/**S**torage';

Then in **providers/service.ts** your code seems to be good.